# Any solution for "Cannot redeclare post_redirect_by_custom_filters()"?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am using below code to redirect all posts of a category to other domain

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;
    // this array can contain category names, slugs or even IDs.
    $catArray = ['HW', '123x', '11x', '111x', '1111x'];
    if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "https://my2nddomain.com/{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
```

But now i want to redirect some category's post to my 3rd site. But when i reuse this code in funtion.php i get this error Cannot redeclare post_redirect_by_custom_filters() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/poster/functions.php

Any solution for that ?

Comment: why not use a different functions name.. or why are you redeclaring the same function?? `add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');` this should do the job.. you don't need to write the same function again.. you can use the previous declared function

Comment: Simply change your function name from post_redirect_by_custom_filters to anything

Comment: changing name of function doesn't work but anyway i found alternative solution that  merge 3 site into 2 then 1 function is enough.